# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Virial theorem is not holding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, virial-theorem

I'm asked to calculate the average Kinetic and Potential Energies for a given state of a quantum harmonic oscillator. The state is:
$$
\psi(x,0) = \left(\dfrac{4m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^\frac{1}{4}e^{\frac{-2m\omega}{\hbar}x^2}
$$
The thing is, calculating
$\langle T\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)(-i\hbar)^2\frac{d^2}{dx}\psi dx=\left(\dfrac{4m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-4m\omega}{h}x^2}dx-\left(\dfrac{4m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{\frac{-4m\omega}{h}x^2}dx=\hbar\omega$

Where I used that the momentum operator is $p=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$

$\langle V\rangle=\dfrac{m\omega^2}{2}\left(\dfrac{4m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{\frac{-4m\omega}{h}x^2}dx=\dfrac{\hbar\omega}{16}$

But then the Virial Theorem is not satisfied. I've read the virial theorem holds for any bound state and all states in a Quantum Harmonic Oscillator are bound. Can someone point out where I am going wrong?
Thank you

Comment: This is the ground state of the Hamiltonian $\frac{1}{2m}\nabla^2 + 8m\omega^2 x^2$ - are you sure that's the state they meant?

Comment: Yes @jacob1729 it's the state I'm given. It's not a ground state, more an infinite sum of QHO eigenstates

Comment: Maybe you could give us more context; what does this state describe etc

Comment: It's a previous exam question, it just states that a QHO of mass m and frequency $\omega$ is in said state at t=0 and asks to calculate <V> and <T>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ground state of the harmonic oscillator is (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) for example): $$\psi_0(x) = \left(\frac{\alpha}{\pi}\right)^{1/4} e^{-\alpha x^2/2},\quad \quad \text{where }\quad \alpha =\frac{ m \omega}{\hbar}$$

Your math is correct, it's just that the state you have is *not* a bound state of the harmonic oscillator, the parameters are slightly off. If you use the state provided above, you can indeed show that: $$\langle T \rangle = \frac{\hbar \omega}{4} = \langle V \rangle.$$

Comment: The state they give me is indeed not the ground state, I need to calculate it for the state given, with that factor of 4

Comment: Sure, except that the Virial theorem in Quantum Mechanics is only true for bound states, and the state you've provided *isn't* a bound state of the Harmonic Oscillator. So it's normal that it doesn't satisfy the theorem. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding as to what a bound state is?

Comment: I read that all states in a quantum harmonic oscillator are bound: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/135456/bound-states-scattering-states-and-infinite-potentials
But maybe I am wrong and for classical energies there existes unbound states?

Comment: That is *also* correct. However, not all **functions** are bound states! A bound state for a particular Hamiltonian $H$ is a state that satisfies$$H \psi = E\psi,$$ where $E$ is a constant number, which we understand to be the energy. I urge you to plug the state that you have into this differential equation to see if it satisfies it.

Comment: That relation is satisfied by eigenfunctions right? That's why they have a definite energy E but my state is an infinte sum of the QHO eigenfunctions with different weight coefficients. So it does not satisfy $H\psi=E\psi$. Thus it is not a bound state so Virial does not hold. Therefore Virial only holds for eigenstates? And Bound states are those of the eigenfunctions?

Comment: Right, I'm not sure I understand the last bit of your comment, but globally, yes. "Bound" and "scattering" are adjectives used to describe states of definite energy (i.e, eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian). Eigenfuctions that have a discrete spectrum are called "bound" and those that have a continuous spectrum are called "scattering". The harmonic oscillator only has eigenfunctions that have a discrete energy spectrum, and therefore all states of definite energy are "bound" states. The Virial theorem only holds for such bound states.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then as a summary, to make sure I have understood:
Virial Theorem holds for bound states, that means eigenfunctions with discrete energy. Singe eigenfunctions of the QHO have discrete energy, all eigenstates are bound. So Virial holds for any QHO eigenstate. However, my state does not have a definite enrgy, since it isn't an eigenstate, so it's not bound, so no Virial.

Comment: That sounds about right, yes!

Answer (score 3):

You can have Gaussian fields that are not eigenstates, but then they are not time independent -- and time independence is the  essential  element of the virial theorem. For example, the harmonic oscillator   time-dependent Schrödinger equation
$$
i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = -\frac 12 \frac {\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} +\frac 12 \omega^2  x^2 \psi
$$
has a time-dependent  solution
$$
\psi(x,t)= \left(\frac{\omega}{\pi}\right)^{1/4}\frac 1{\sqrt{e^{i \omega  t} +R e^{-i\omega   t}}}\exp\left\{ - \frac \omega 2    \left(\frac{1-R\,e^{-2i\omega   t}}{1+R\,e^{-2i\omega  t}}\right)x^2\right\},
$$
where the parameter $|R|<1$. Only if $R=0$ are  its $x$ and $p$ distributions time independent. If $R\ne 0$ the gaussian "breathes" in and out. Your wavefunction is a snapshot of this one at some particular time.

Below is a visualisation of $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ (taking $\omega=1$) for different values of $R$, showing how the Gaussian "breathes". As you can see, as $R\to 0$, the probability distribution tends to not change as much.

[image]

Comment: *The gaussian "breathes" in and out*. That's one heck of an image, I'm going to use that phrase from now on. :P

Comment: I don't think I understand the "breathes in and out" metaphor. Can you expand on that?

Comment: I mean that if you plot $|\psi(x,t)|^2$ for my solution as a function of time you will see that the gaussian  expands and contracts with frequency $2\omega$. Thus   $<x^2>$. and $<p^2>$ shrink  and  grow periodically. Of course   $<p^2>$ grows as $<x^2>$ shrinks..

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you

Comment: @mikestone Hello! I've added a small GIF and a little description illustrating what I think you meant, please feel free to remove it/edit it/rollback the edit, etc. as you see fit!

Comment: @Phillip  That's great!